# Does anyone know how to get the hours for markets such as the NYSE on TD Ameritrade API?

Tags: api, html-table, ameritrade

I'm trying to request hour information from the TD Ameritrade API. Is there any way I could get the hours for the New York Stock Exchange?

Here is the link to the API:
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TD Ameritrade's API provides an endpoint for [market hours](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/market-hours/apis/get/marketdata/%7Bmarket%7D/hours) however you can't specify which exchange to check, only which market (BOND, EQUITY, ETF etc..).

For some reason, it allows you to specify which date but it *only accepts the current date*. Providing an access token doesn't do anything so I won't be including a header with the token in my example.

```
import json
import urllib.request

api_key = 'PRIVATE'


def get_market_hours(market, date):

    params = f'?apikey={api_key}&date={date}'
    url = f'https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/{market}/hours' + params

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        text_bytes = response.read()

    text_str = text_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    text_json = json.loads(text_str)

    print(text_json)


get_market_hours('EQUITY', '2020-12-23')
```

According to their site, most of [NYSE](https://www.nyse.com/markets/hours-calendars) is open 06:30 - 20:00 EST, it might be easier to just check if the current time is within that timeframe and if the current day is not a holiday.

Comment: Did you figure this out or do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget and JSON feed on https://www.isthemarketopen.com/ - It's an atomic clock for the U.S. Stock Market

Here is the code to simply embed their widget:

```
<iframe src="https://www.isthemarketopen.com/widget/#/" width="565" height="200" frameBorder="0">Browser not compatible.</iframe>
```

Here is their JSON feed

```
https://www.isthemarketopen.com/static/markets.json
```